# I can't install SSH2 PHP extension on Centos 7

Tags: ssh2

When I make the command:

```
yum install gcc php-devel libssh2 libssh2-devel php-pear make
```

Return me below:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 104.219.172.10
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 104.219.172.10
 * cpanel-plugins: 104.219.172.10
 * remi-php74: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * remi-safe: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
Package gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No php-devel package available.
Package libssh2-1.8.0-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libssh2-devel-1.8.0-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No php-pear package available.
Package 1: make-3.82-24.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

When I run the `pecl install -f ssh2 command`

returns me:

```
bash: pecl: command not found
```

I can't install pecl either, I tried `yum install php-pear` but it returns:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 104.219.172.10
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 104.219.172.10
 * cpanel-plugins: 104.219.172.10
 * remi-php74: mirror.bebout.net
 * remi-safe: mirror.bebout.net
No php-pear package available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: If you use php from "remi-php74", you can simply install php-pecl-ssh2... nearly all extensions are available in the repository

Comment: Notice: cpanel is not centos, too much altered distribution.